# Titanium and nodejs chat implementaion

Tags: node.js, socket.io, titanium, appcelerator

I am trying to implement a chat app, that uses node js as the backend server and Titanium framework for the UI.

I am trying to implement something like this
http://roguesynaptics.com/post/7076349551/chatsocks-native
rather, exactly like this.

But problem is, I cannot understand how these two things are connected, i.e node server and Titanium's app.js.

in the video, as shown, in the terminal the command "node app.js" is run, Is it the same app.js file as present in the Titanium. I think it isn't, but cant find any other assumption. can anyone please walk me through on how to implement this?
I am newbee to node js.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `node app.js` you are actually running NodeJS server. That server listens on port  3000. Later your Titanium application is connecting to this port and sends/receives messages via sockets. That's what Socket.io is used for.